# XPath query for known value attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<Header>
  <Reference>
    <Identifier>BatchProcessed</Identifier>
    <DateTime>2011-08-15T05:12:00+10:00</DateTime>
  </Reference>
</Header>
<Header>
  <Reference>
    <Identifier>Running</Identifier>
    <DateTime>2011-08-15T05:12:00+10:00</DateTime>
  </Reference>
</Header>
```

I'm trying to use an XPath query to find out this value "BatchProcessed" in Identifier.

Please correct me. This what I have in my query but it's not working:

```
//Header[Identifier='BatchProcessed']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifier is inside of Reference, so you need to add that to your XPath. Either

```
//Header[Reference/Identifier='BatchProcessed']
```

or

```
//Header[.//Identifier='BatchProcessed']
```

Comment: some how it throws exception ,please correct me what am doing   XmlNode node = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("///Header[contains(.//Identifier, 'BatchProcessed')]");  Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Comment: @user832967 The triple `/` in front of `///Header` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but...

```
//Header/Reference/Identifier/text() == 'BatchProcessed'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//Header[contains(.//Identifier, 'BatchProcessed')]
```

It reads, "find a Header element anywhere below root which has a descendant element called Identifier that contains 'BatchProcessed' in its text node.

You have to be a little careful using text in an element as white space can sometimes through you off, especially if you start throwing comments in there.  This is why I used "contains" rather than a simple equality -- even though an equality would work for you particular document.  In my opinion, it's better to make the identifier an attribute as you can't throw comments into attributes.

Comment: i tried your's also got the same issue  it throws exception ,please correct me what am doing XmlNode node = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("///Header[contains(.//Identifier, 'BatchProcessed')]"); Expression must evaluate to a node-set.